# Javascript Array of objects get single value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have an array of objects:

```
var employees=[]
employees[0]={name:"George", age:32, retiredate:"March 12, 2014"}
employees[1]={name:"Edward", age:17, retiredate:"June 2, 2023"}
employees[2]={name:"Christine", age:58, retiredate:"December 20, 2036"}
employees[3]={name:"Sarah", age:62, retiredate:"April 30, 2020"}
```

Is there an array function that will allow me to get one property as an array,
for example:

```
namesArray = employees.reduceToProperty('name'); // none existent function i made up!

// should return ["George","Edward","Christine","Sarah"]
```

I know how get the desired result with a loop, I am just hoping for an array function or combination of functions exist that can do this in one line.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/218196

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used to map one array to another.

```
var names = employees.map(function(i) {
  return i.name;
});
```

`names` is now an array containing the `name`-properties of the objects.

Comment: it was an easy one :) - there are more usefull array functions, take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: The (cleaner) ES6 sayntax is: `const names = employees.map((i) => i.name)` (Just making [tickietackie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9119176/tickietackie) comment to update this old solution more readable)

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) maps one array to another:

```
var names = employees.map(function (val) {
    return val.name;
});
// ['George', 'Edward', 'Christine', 'Sarah']
```

Comment: I marked this answer as a duplicate to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036033/4575793). That was declined because it was answered only a minute later, but I still think, we don't need the same answer twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing this frequently, you might consider using `pluck` from Underscore/Lo-Dash:

```
var listOfPropertyNames = _.pluck(list, 'propertyName');
```

- [underscorejs.org/#pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)
- [lodash.com/docs#pluck](http://lodash.com/docs#pluck)

If you don't want to do include a library, it is of course possible to write your own `pluck` for use on your code base:

```
function pluck(list, propertyName) {
  return list.map(function(i) {
    return i[propertyName];
  });
}
```

And running it:

```
pluck([{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}], 'name');
["a", "b"]
```

You'll have to decide how to handle the edge cases like:

- object in the list not having the property
- an `undefined` being in the list
- ?